# Put TextBox into editing mode programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, textbox

I am modifying a multi-column listview in order to be able to edit its cells. When the user clicks into an already selected cell, a TextBox shall be shown and by subsequently typing a text, the cell content shall be changed (after confirmation with enter of course).

But when I use the method below, the TextBox appears, but it does not seem to be focused, and so does not get into editing mode: the caret is not shown and typing with the keyboard does not change the Text field of the TextBox. Only after clicking into the TextBox a second time the caret appears.

```
public void startEditing(TableIndex cell)
{
    editedCell = cell;
    editTextBox.Bounds = CellBounds(cell);
    editTextBox.Text = this[editedCell.RowIndex, editedCell.ColumnIndex];
    editTextBox.Show();
    editTextBox.Focus();
}
```

How can I put the TextBox into editing mode programmatically?

Before anyone bothers to suggest: no, I don't want to switch to DataGridView and such. Everytime I have tried to use them, they were so slow it made me feel like I was emulating Windows on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Where/How do you call `startEditing`? Please share [MCVE].

Comment: Okay I will prepare something... I thought that focusing a child control is a common task that doesn't need a reproducible example.

Comment: At least we need to know where you are calling this method.  `MouseDown` event for example? Also values of some of the `ListView` properties, like `FullRowSelect`.

Comment: I am calling it in ListView.OnMouseDown. But anyway, I'll try to prepare a complete example.

Comment: Move your code to MouseUp and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: Cool, call yourself super hero. It works now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OP: I am calling it in ListView.OnMouseDown.

Show and focus the editor control in `OnMouseUp`.

The `ListView` handles [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListView.cs,58f392e349363042) and pushes a focus which means after processing your `OnMouseDown` code, the `ListView` will get the focus.

The easiest fix for you to make the `TextBox` get the focus, would be showing the `TextBox` and focusing in in `OnMouseUp`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling an event handler on the listView like `listView.ItemSelectionChanged` the focus goes back to the listView box after the eventHandler is triggered, this is why it swaps back to selecting the listView.

You can work around this by having another a GotFocus eventHandler after the original one and having this set the focus to the textBox.

```
this.listView1.ItemSelectionChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventHandler( this.listView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
this.listView1.GotFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_Focused);

private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//call startEditing code
}

private void listView1_Focused(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
editTextBox.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work, at least not in my case. I have followed RezaAghaei's suggestion which did the trick. Thanks anyway.